# Insert multiple values in one field SQL with Subquery

Tags: sql, insert, subquery

i have a a table called messages and a table called customer

I want to insert a new message in the message table for every customer ID in the customers table.
I wrote the below query

```
INSERT INTO MESSAGES
(
ID,
VERSION,
CUSTOMERID,
SERVICE,
CREATED_BY,
MESSAGE
)
VALUES
(
NEWID(),
'1',
SELECT id FROM customer,
null,
'test',
'test')
```

But i get the error

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
Any ideas?

Comment: JUST TO ADD that i only need the customer_id from the customer table and no other data

Answer (score 2):

Not possible, try this:

```
INSERT INTO MESSAGES
(ID, VERSION, CUSTOMERID, SERVICE, CREATED_BY, MESSAGE)
SELECT NEWID(), '1', id,  null, 'test', 'test'
FROM customer
```

In this way you can insert in your message table all customer rows

Comment: Fields' number in INSERT and in SELECT must be the same. In that query by CUSTOMER table you'll get only ID field, the others are constants